# template page to show custom a post types only

Tags: custom-post-types

Does anyone know how to make this page template to only show knowledgebase post types?
I've tried various different ways but with no luck

```
<?php
  $cat_args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'knowledgebase_category', 
 'orderby' => 'slug',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'hierarchical' => true,
 'parent' => 0,
  'child_of' => 0
  );

 $categories = get_categories($cat_args); 
 $catCounter = 7;
 foreach($categories as $category) { 
 $catCounter++;
 if ($catCounter == 1) { 
 echo '</div><div class="row knowledge-base">';
 } 
 elseif ($catCounter == 8) {
 $catCounter = 1;
 echo '<div class="row knowledge-base">';
 }
 elseif ($catCounter == 3) { 
 $catCounter = 0;
 } 

 echo '<div class="span3">';
 echo '<h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . title="'            .         $category->name . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></h2>';

// Sub category
$sub_category = get_category($category);
$subcat_args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'child_of' => $sub_category->cat_ID,
'parent' => $sub_category->cat_ID
 );
 $sub_categories = get_categories($subcat_args); 

 foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category) { 
echo '<ul class="sub-categories">';
echo '<li><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> <a href="' . get_category_link(          $sub_category->term_id ) . '" title="' . $sub_category->name .     '" ' . '>' . $sub_category->name.'</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
    }


    //List Posts

    // Smart Lists
    $cat_post_num = gt_get_option('kb_aticles_per_cat');

    $sub_category_num = count($sub_categories);
    if ($sub_category_num != 0) {
    $cat_post_num_smart = $cat_post_num - $sub_category_num;
     } else {
    $cat_post_num_smart = $cat_post_num;    
    }
    $posts_order = '' ;// of_get_option('st_hp_cat_posts_order');


   global $post;
    // Listed by popular?
    $cat_post_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'knowledgebase',
   'numberposts' => $cat_post_num_smart,
      'orderby' => $posts_order,

     );

    $cat_posts = get_posts($cat_post_args);
    echo '<ul class="category-posts">';
    foreach($cat_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    if (get_post_format() == 'video') {
    $post_icon = 'icon-film';
    } elseif (get_post_format() == 'image') {
     $post_icon = 'icon-picture';
    } else {
    $post_icon = 'icon-file';
     }
    ?>

      <li><i class="<?php echo $post_icon; ?>"></i> <a href="<?php the_permalink();       ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

   <?php 
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
     echo '<span class="label label-color"><a href="' . get_category_link(                 $category->term_id ) . '" title="" ' . '>View all ' .     $category->count .' articles <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></span>';
    echo '</div>';
     } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do a complete rewrite in the end also using a complete different post type approach

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand of your snippet post retrieval is implemented by `get_posts($cat_post_args)` call and so results are controlled by `$cat_post_args` arguments.

To add post type limitation to it you should add `post_type` argument to that array. See documentation on [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) (used internally and documents available argument more thoroughly).

Comment: hi i tried `'post_type' => 'knowledgebase',` in `$cat_post_args` im afraid that didn't work `<?php
$cat_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'knowledgebase',
  'orderby' => 'slug',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'parent' => 0,
  'child_of' => 0
);
`

Comment: And?.. :) Did it work?

Comment: no sorry it didn't

Comment: i also tried `'post_type' => array('knowledgebase'),` and that didnt work

Comment: I've modified the code above to reflect the changes made, so far i can see the categories and posts, but not the correct posts to the correct categories